# How can you assign all the different values in a table variable to fields in existing rows of a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table variable (`@tableVar`) with one column (`tableCol`) of unique values.

I have a target table with many existing rows that also has a column that is filled entirely with the NULL value.

What type of statement can I use to iterate through `@tableVar` and assign a different value from `@tableVar.tableCol` to the null field for each of the rows in my target table?

*Edit (to provide info)
My Target table has this structure:

```
+-------+------------+
| Name  | CallNumber |
+-------+------------+
| James | NULL       |
| Byron | NULL       |
| Steve | NULL       |
+-------+------------+
```

My table variable has this structure

```
+------------+
| CallNumber |
+------------+
|       6348 |
|       2675 |
|       9898 |
+------------+
```

I need to assign a different call number to each row in the target table, to achieve this kind of result.

```
+-------+------------+
| Name  | CallNumber |
+-------+------------+
| James |       6348 |
| Byron |       2675 |
| Steve |       9898 |
+-------+------------+
```

Note: Each row does not need a specific CallNumber. The only requirement is that each row have a unique CallNumber.  For example, "James" does not specifically need 6348; He can have any number as long as it's unique, and the unique number must come from the table variable.  You can assume that the table variable will have enough CallNumbers to meet this requirement.

What type of query can I use for this result?

Comment: FYI: You should almost never need to iterate through records in SQL. SQL is set-based and you have to modify your thinking to think in sets of data rather than individual rows.

Comment: @DaleK You're right; I have updated my question with sample data and expected results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `update` with a sequence number:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from target t
     )
update toupdate
     set col = tv.tablecol
     from (select tv.*, row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
           from @tablevar tv
          ) tv
     where tv.seqnum = toupdate.seqnum;
```

This assumes that `@tablevar` has a sufficient number of rows to assign in `target`.  If not, I would suggest that you ask a *new* question with sample data and desired results.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d7146e59bb4303bf9641512098a966e1) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks but I'm having trouble with this solution.  I've updated my question with more details if you're interested

Comment: @DalhousieDuck . . . There was a typo in the query.  I fixed that and added a db<>fiddle.

Comment: @DaleK I made the update based on the typo and changed the variable names around to fit my model and it now works, thanks.